# ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/chronos/utils/type-checks.d.ts(8,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Extract'

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have tried to use bsdatepicker in my code, for that I have imported BsDatepickerModule from ngx-bootstrap. I am getting this error

> ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/chronos/utils/type-checks.d.ts(8,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Extract'.

I have attached my package.json for your reference.

I have tried changing/updating versions of rxjs, could not fix it.

```
{
  "name": "notification-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

I need to use bsdatepicker in my code without these errors.[image: Error Screenshot]

Output for ng version

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 11.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.3
@angular/cli                      6.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.4
@schematics/angular               0.6.3
@schematics/update                0.6.3
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.28.4
```

Comment: Hi! can you update your question with what you get from the cli if you type `ng -version` from your root folder?

Comment: can you try first with updating your cli to 6.0.8 and then remove your node_modules folder and then do `npm install` again in your root folder?

Comment: I have tried as per you have told, I am getting the same error. @Lucho

Comment: can you update post again with the acutal bootstrap installed with `npm list ngx-bootstrap`?

Comment: Thanks for providing suggestions, I have fixed the error and I have specified in the answer section.@L

Comment: I looked at the answer, and it's really not a solution as it's a really big downgrade of version which probably causes other problems that been fixed on later version and along with compatibility issues most likely.  It would be great if you could provide an update on the post from `npm list ngx-bootstrap` just to determine which version was being installed

Comment: The output for `npm list ngx-bootstap` is `ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5`

Comment: Before you changed it

Comment: Before I had ^4.1.1 version for ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Ngx-DatePicker'.

```
npm install ngx-date-picker --save
```

Comment: I have tried other datepickers, but bsdatepicker is best suited for my code as per look and requirements ('MM/DD/YYYY'). So, only I am trying to include it.

I was using it in previous version. Now, I am trying to update my project to new framework primeng, now when i try to use bsdatepicker. I am getting error. Exactly when I import this module I am getting this error. Please help me to resolve this.!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.!!

I have fixed the error in my code. I changed the ngx-bootstrap version to 2.0.5

> sudo npm install ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5

Then the bsdatepicker was working without error, but the UI was not as expected. So,I included this line at the top of the component were I am using it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css">
```

Now, I got my expected output.!